# Null Pointer Exception While calling MySql Database

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception, netbeans-7, nullreferenceexception

I'm practicing a Java Netbeans program where I'm calling values from MySql Database but it's giving me this Exception of Null Pointer. I'm new to this so please help me solve this problem.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at cooling.system.pkg1.pkg0.Calculation1.calculate(Calculation1.java:371)
at cooling.system.pkg1.pkg0.Calculation1.btn_setActionPerformed(Calculation1.java:1081)
at cooling.system.pkg1.pkg0.Calculation1.access$1000(Calculation1.java:22)
at cooling.system.pkg1.pkg0.Calculation1$11.actionPerformed(Calculation1.java:862)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

and this is my code:

```
public void calculate() throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    if(!(chckbx_current_value.isSelected()))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select Current value");
    }
    if(chckbx_big_close_value.isSelected() && chckbx_small_close_value.isSelected())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select Only one closest value");
        chckbx_big_close_value.setSelected(false);
        chckbx_small_close_value.setSelected(false);
    }
    else if(!(chckbx_big_close_value.isSelected()) && !(chckbx_small_close_value.isSelected()))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Select Atleast one closest value");
    }
    Connection con=null;
    try 
    {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/coolingSystem","root","password");
                String small = "select * from dryAir_properties where T = "+closest_small+"";
                PreparedStatement ps_small = con.prepareStatement(small);
                ResultSet rs_small = ps_small.executeQuery();


                String big = "select * from dryAir_properties where T = "+closest_big+"";
                PreparedStatement ps_big = con.prepareStatement(big);
                ResultSet rs_big = ps_big.executeQuery();
                while(rs_small.next() && rs_big.next())
                {
                    Cp_big = Float.valueOf(rs_big.getString(3));
                    k_big = Float.valueOf(rs_big.getString(4));
                    viscosity_big = Float.valueOf(rs_big.getString(5));
                    density_big = Float.valueOf(rs_big.getString(6));

                    Cp_small = Float.valueOf(rs_small.getString(3));
                    k_small = Float.valueOf(rs_small.getString(4));
                    viscosity_small = Float.valueOf(rs_small.getString(5));
                    density_small = Float.valueOf(rs_small.getString(6));
                } 
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException | SQLException  e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error...... "+e);
    }

    float Cp = (((tma - closest_small)*(Cp_big - Cp_small))/(closest_big - closest_small)) + Cp_big;
    float k = (((tma - closest_small)*(k_big - k_small))/(closest_big - closest_small)) + k_big;
    float viscosity = (((tma - closest_small)*(viscosity_big - viscosity_small))/(closest_big - closest_small)) + viscosity_big;
    float density = (((tma - closest_small)*(density_big - density_small))/(closest_big - closest_small)) + density_big;
    txt_Cp_a.setText(String.valueOf(Cp));
    txt_Conductivity_a.setText(String.valueOf(k));
    txt_Viscosity_a.setText(String.valueOf(viscosity));
    txt_Density_a.setText(String.valueOf(density));
}
```

Comment: Warning... SQL injection...

Comment: what are you talking about this isn't the problem

Comment: If any value is null in the database, `Float.valueOf` will give that exception. `If s is null, then a NullPointerException is thrown.`

Comment: @fge Not necessarily if the values concatenated are integers.

Comment: Please I have provided the full information now... Help me im stucked

Comment: Which line is exactly line 371 in Calculation1.java ?

Comment: @Ravi Longia You'd need to help us helping you. Sanjeev asked you which is the line where the error is thrown, but you didn't answer. This is quite a key question.

Comment: @Saneev 5th line in the Code.... this one PreparedStatement ps_small = con.prepareStatement(small);

Comment: @Saneev and in Netbeans there is hint flashing on that line that is (Null Pointer Dereferencing.)

Comment: Ok, it looks like your `Connection` object is null. Can you please point us to more code, especially where the `Connection` is expected to be created?

Comment: @Andrei Nicusan  Now I have provided you the whole funtion code...Please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 possible causes why `DriverManager.getConnection` returns `null`.

1. The JDBC URL is invalid. Please check if your MySQL server runs on your machine on the default port (3306). If not, please include the port explicitly in the URL. Then, `coolingSystem` should be the name of an existing database on your server (not a table or something else). Last, please double check your credentials.
2. The driver is not included in the runtime classpath. Does `Class.forName` throw any exception/error? Please check the logs for this purpose.

Comment: Your answer is great but this isn't the problem but, I got a very strange solution of my problem where i'm trying to execute a Linear Interpolation equation i moved it in try block and its working now....this shouldn't be the answer but its working good now its very strange........!!! Whyy

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mysql-connector in your classpath? It seems like Connection is null.
Test if Connection is null and print it out, just to check.

Comment: No its fine and problem is solved in very strange way...thankyou for your help :)